# Чем отличается JavaScript от ES6 и EC2015?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Собственно, вопрос: чем отличается JavaScript от ES6, EC2015 и TypeScript? 
Никто мне толком не может ответить по существу.
Зачем для Angular 2 мне нужен именно TS?

Comment: Потому что в ES6 много [нового](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLqHlAwsJRxAOpWPtj2T6HhSzX-lKmKV2q). А ведь еще есть рекомендации для ES7, например async/await В angular2 вам **не обязательно** нужен TS, просто подавляющее большинство примеров на TS.

Comment: то есть ec5/6 для javascript это как sass для css?

Comment: нет, это спека JS. У JS, как и у других языков есть новые версии, новые спецификации. Это не как sass для css, это как python 2 и python 3. В вашем вопросе скорее TS как sass для css. Вас может смутить необходимость транспилировать ES6 в ES5 - это необходимо для того, чтобы ваш код, написанный на ES6 мог работать во всех браузерах, которые еще не поддерживают ES6.

Comment: _Зачем для Angular 2 мне нужен именно TS?_ - ни зачем. Для Ангуляр2 можно использовать JS, TS, Dart

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript от ES6 и ES2015 ничем не отличается.

JavaScript - это исторически сложившиеся название языка программирования.

ES - ECMAScript - Это спецификация JavaScript, в которой описано как этот язык должен работать.

ES5, ES6 - Это версии этой спецификации.

ES2015 - Это второе название ES6, начиная с этой версии каждое следующая спецификация будет включать в себя год в котором сделана.

TS - TypeScript - Это язык на основе JS расширяющий его возможности. Работает как SCSS.

Для Angular 2 выбрали TypeScript как раз из за его возможностей. Сам Angular2 написан на TypeScript. Приложения на Angular 2 можно писать и на ES6 и на ES5, но стандартный Туториал написан на TS.

Comment: Отличный ответ, я бы только "JavaScript от ES6 и ES2015 ничем не отличается.", так как это не совсем так.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Поясните, почему и чем они отличаются?

Comment: Ну это как помидор и огурец, понимаете? JavaScript — это язык программирования, EcmaScript — это спецификация. Почему вы решили, что это одно и то же?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Да, я имел ввиду, что когда мы говорим JS/ES6/ES2015 мы говорим, по сути, об одном, о JS.
Так проще для понимания, ES === JS :)

Comment: Вообще, я думал, что любой начинающий в JS начинает свой путь с http://learn.javascript.ru/ где в самом начале поясняют большую часть вопросов топикстартера

Answer (score 0):

Все языки развиваются. Javascript делает это медленнее из-за паравоза браузеров, которые нужно поддерживать.

Вместе с тем, на JS пишутся очень большие и сложные приложения, поэтому без развития никуда. Слабая типизация JS и отсутствие нормального ООП не позволяет писать на нем надежные масштабируемые приложения.

ES6 (ECMA2015) расширяет стандарт новыми возможностями, такие как классы.

Typescript просто имплементирует их и позволяет уже сейчас писать на ES6 + типизированно. Просто попробуйте: [начать](http://typescript-lang.ru/docs/) просто, можно писать как и на JS.

Comment: "Включаю режим зануды": 1. А что, надежные масштабируемые приложения без ооп никак писать нельзя?  2. В js таки полноценных классов с точки зрения java-like ооп нет, ключевое слово class - это мелкий сахарок, есть в стандарте и более интересные вещи

Comment: Ну вообще это мелочные придирки конечно, так я плюсанул)